# Suggested edits need to age away or be retractable

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently made edits on both questions and tag wikis and have had them stagnate in the review queue without any decision for four days now. I am currently unable to make any additional edits, obviously because you may only have 5 (6 if you submit tag wiki/description edits) at a given time.

The only reasonable conclusion is that my edits for whatever reason are ambiguous enough that they are just being skipped in the review queue. I am also under the impression that it requires more reputation to approve tag wiki suggested edits and therefore less people to approve those.

I think that there needs to be a way for edit suggestions to be retracted/age away similar to how the flagging system works, as I am currently stuck in a perpetual state of limbo unable to make any further reputation or badge progress through suggested edits.

Comment: I think letting users retract their suggested edits is useful. A bit of a narrow case but useful. They shouldn't age away automatically, though.

Comment: AFAIK, users can already retract their suggested edits by editing back to the original post. Granted, it's not that simple.

Comment: In this case, someone created a tag we really don't need. I made it a synonym with [caret] (which itself might be too granular). In the future, it's worth asking if a new tag is useful or not. The lone question with it [was asking about a single feature of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096976/reactivate-multi-caret-shortcut-after-resharper-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is most likely the tag wiki edits.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30474988
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30449156

Tag wiki edits require [5000 rep to approve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), unlike other edits that only require 2000 rep, so there are fewer possible reviewers.

Additionally, tag wiki approvals require the approver to search for plagiarism as that's rife in such edits, and the need to do so does seem to put off some of those that could otherwise do approvals. Note that I'm not saying your edits are plagiarised, however they do miss [the point of the tag wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

> - The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag.
> - Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized.
> - Concentrate on what a tag means to your community.
> - Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.

And perhaps that's why people are skipping them because they don't fix everything that's wrong with those wikis.